# Deleting data in pandas

Tags: pandas

Please forgive me if my questions is easy but I am very new in the programming game. How can I delete all the data that starts with a `-` in my data set with a 'no' value without compromising the spacing of the columns.

```
20140331 220452    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 221051    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0     1.0     1.5   -32.0   -24.6     1.5
20140331 221651    -32.0   -32.0    -0.5   -32.0     6.0     0.0     9.0     7.0     6.5    -7.6     9.0
20140331 222252    -32.0   -32.0    -4.0   -32.0     1.5     2.0     8.5     8.0     1.5    -8.7     8.5
20140331 222852    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 223451      0.5     1.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -24.7     1.0
20140331 224052      9.5   -32.0   -32.0     9.0     9.5   -32.0     8.0     9.0     9.5    -4.6     9.5
20140331 224652    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 225252    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 225852    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 230452    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 231051    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 231652    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 232252    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 232852    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 233451    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 234052    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 234652      2.5     2.0   -32.0     2.5   -32.0   -32.0     2.5     2.0   -32.0   -12.9     2.5
20140331 235252    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
20140331 235853    -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0   -32.0
```

Comment: Sorry you want to replace negative values with `nan`?

Comment: you can just do `df[df<0]` if that's what you want

Comment: Can you post desired output

Answer (score 1):

Use array masking to select the desired data and then assign with numpy's NaN. Assuming these are floats,

```
df[df < 0] = np.nan
```